# Can you put $self into a Thread::Queue in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop, concurrency

I'm having issues with trying to put $self into the thread queue.  Perl complains about CODE refs.  Is it possible to put an object instance onto the thread queue?

```
generic.pm (Superclass)

package Things::Generic;

use Thread::Queue;
use threads;

our $work_queue = new Thread::Queue;
our $result_queue = new Thread::Queue;

my @worker_pool = map { threads->create (\&delegate_task, $work_queue, $result_queue) } 1 .. $MAX_THREADS;

sub delegate_task {
    my( $Qwork, $Qresults ) = @_;
    while( my $work = $Qwork->dequeue ) {
            #The item on the queue contains "self" taht was passed in, 
            #  so call it's do_work method

            $work->do_work();
            $Qresults->enqueue( "lol" );
    }

    $Qresults->enqueue( undef ); ## Signal this thread is finished
}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {
            _options => shift,
    };

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
.
.
.
#other instance methods
```

#### #

```
object.pm (Subclass)
package Things::Specific;

use base qw ( Things::Generic )

sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);

        return $self;
}

sub do_stuff {
     my $self = shift;
     $Things::Generic::work_queue->enqueue($self);
}

sub do_work {
     print "DOING WORK\n";
}
```

Comment: It's not the object it has a problem with; it's with a code ref within. I don't have Perl on this machine to verify this, but it seems you can't share code refs. That's not unreasonable. Why are you trying to share objects with code refs? You should be sharing data.

Comment: Who converted my answer into a comment? It's in no way a comment! It identifies both the direct problem the OP is experiencing and his design problem.

Comment: Three side problems: 1) Your Job object ("Things::Specific") shouldn't be a subclass of your supervisor ("Things::Generic"). 2) "Things::Specific" is a an awful name of a Job and "Things::Generic" is an awful name of a supervisor. 3) Module should have the same name as their package declaration `(Things/Generic.pm` and `Things/Specific.pm`, not `generic.pm` and `object.pm`.)

Comment: I just mocked this up.  I change the names and function from my real code to something similar to demonstrate the exact issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not objects it has a problem with; it's with a code ref within. That's not unreasonable. Why are you trying to share objects with code refs? You should be sharing data between threads, not code.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not certain of this, the likely root cause is not that you're passing an object, but that the object in question is storing an anonymous coderef in it (a callback, iterator, or the like). You may be able to refactor the object to eliminate this or perform some sort of serialization that allows it to recreate the coderef in the other thread.